# Error in program.cs file, some services are not being constructed

Tags: c#

When I run my code I get the following error "ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]'.)" in my progrmas.cs file, the frame work am building in is .netcore 3.1

```
//Error happens in this class at CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
         public class Program
                {
                    public static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
                    }
            
                    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                            {
                                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                            });
                }
        //controller class Login and registration
                [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
                    public class IdentifyMe : Controller
                    {
                        private readonly IIdentify _identify;
                
                        public IdentifyMe(IIdentify identifying)
                        {
                            _identify = identifying;
                        }
                
                        [HttpGet(Api_Routes.Identity.Register)]
                        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserRegistration register)
                        {
                            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                            {
                                return BadRequest(new Unauthenticated
                                {
                                    Errors=ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x=>x.Errors.Select(xx=>xx.ErrorMessage))
                                });
                            }
                
                
                            var authresponce = await _identify.RegisterAsync(register.Email, register.Password, register.User_Name);
                
                            if (!authresponce.Success)
                            {
                                return BadRequest(new Unauthenticated
                                {
                                    Errors = authresponce.Errors
                                });
                            }
                            return Ok(new Authenticated
                            {
                                Token = authresponce.Token
                            });
                        }
                
                
                
                        [HttpGet(Api_Routes.Identity.Login)]
                        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsync(User_login login)
                        {
                            var authresponce = await _identify.LoginAsync(login.Password, login.email);
                
                            if (!authresponce.Success)
                            {
                                return BadRequest(new Unauthenticated
                                {
                                    Errors = authresponce.Errors
                                });
                            }
                            return Ok(new Authenticated
                            {
                                Token = authresponce.Token
                            });
                        }
                
                
                    }
                
                // service registration
                
                public class Dbinstaller : IInstaller
                {
                    public void Cleanner(IConfiguration configuration, IServiceCollection services)
                    {
                        var jwt = new JWTsettings();
                        configuration.Bind(nameof(jwt), jwt);
                        services.AddSingleton(jwt);
                
                        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
                        {
                            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        })
                            .AddJwtBearer(x =>
                            {
                                x.SaveToken = true;
                                var TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                                {
                                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwt.Secret)),
                                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                                    ValidateAudience = false,
                                    RequireExpirationTime = false,
                                    ValidateLifetime = true
                                };
                            });
                
                
                        services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
                        {
                            x.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TXC API", Version = "v1" });
                
                            var security = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>
                            {
                                {"Bearer", new string[0]}
                            };
                
                            x.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                                { 
                                 Description="JWT Authorization Header using the bearer scheme",
                                 Name="Authorization",
                                 In=ParameterLocation.Header,
                                 Type=SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
                                });
                            x.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                            {
                                {new OpenApiSecurityScheme{Reference=new OpenApiReference
                                {
                                    Id="Bearer",
                                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme
                                }
                                },new List<string>() }
                            });
                        });
                
                        
                
                
                
                        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
                        opt.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("TXC Connection")));
                        services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>();
                    }
                }
               
    //service implementation class
        public class Identify : IIdentify
            {
                private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _manager;
        
                private readonly JWTsettings jwtset;
        
        
        
                public Identify(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager, JWTsettings jW)
                {
                    _manager = userManager;
                    jwtset = jW;
                }
        
               
        
                public async Task<Authentication_result> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string Username)
                {
                    var exists = _manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        
                    if (exists != null)
                    {
                        return new Authentication_result
                        {
                            Errors = new[] { "User with this email already exists" }
                        };
                    }
        
                    var newPerson = new IdentityUser
                    {
                        Email = email,
                        UserName = Username
                    };
        
                    var Creation = await _manager.CreateAsync(newPerson, password);
        
                    if (!Creation.Succeeded)
                    {
                        return new Authentication_result
                        {
                            Errors = new[] { "Invalid user!" }
                        };
                    }
        
                    return Generate_Authentication_Result(newPerson);
                }
        
                public async Task<Authentication_result> LoginAsync(string email, string Password)
                {
                    var user = await _manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
        
                    if (user == null)
                    {
                        return new Authentication_result
                        {
                            Errors = new[] { "User does not exists" }
                        };
                    }
        
                    var validate_password = await _manager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, Password);
        
                    if (!validate_password)
                    {
                        return new Authentication_result
                        {
                            Errors = new[] { "" }
                        };
                    }
        
                    return Generate_Authentication_Result(user);
                }
        
                private Authentication_result Generate_Authentication_Result(IdentityUser newPerson)
                {
                    var Tokenhandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jwtset.Secret);
                    var TokenDescripter = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
                    {
                        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                       {
                           new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, newPerson.Email),
                           new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                           new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, newPerson.Email),
                           new Claim("id",newPerson.Id)
        
                       }),
        
                        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
                        SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
                    };
        
                    var token = Tokenhandler.CreateToken(TokenDescripter);
        
                    return new Authentication_result
                    {
                        Success = true,
                        Token = Tokenhandler.WriteToken(token)
                    };
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is username/password backwards? var authresponce = await _identify.LoginAsync(login.Password, login.email);

Comment: Thank you so much, yeah they were can't believe I didn't notice that but the error still persists nothings changed unfortunately.

Comment: If you know anyone that can help me out please do try and see if you can get them to, this bug has been a bit of a thorn in my side.

Comment: The best way of debugging is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Check if you see the TLS authentification.  You should see in the response a 200 OK status, or a 400/500 error status.  I believe the TLS is failing.  I help solved lots of these issues.  Need to see status error.

Comment: Ok, so am looking for a status response, got that much but in my case am dealing with a compile time error, the app breaks with ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser] Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' .........errors.

Comment: Make sure you are running with latest API's. Try clean build.  Did code work with Core 2.1?  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/2.2-3.0   Also see following : https://www.reflections-ibs.com/blog/articles/how-to-extend-asp-net-core-3-0-and-3-1-identity-user

Comment: I stated with 3.0 then upgraded to 3.1, I've never used 2.1

Comment: Alright thanks, will get back to you with the results

Comment: Hi, so it took my a little while but I finally was able to use the information you directed me to specific to my issue, thank you so much..